# OpenVPN Connect Client Mac only working after fresh install

Tags: vpn, openvpn, mac

I'm facing a problem that I can't be sure what the root of the problem is.

I am using OpenVPN Connect Client MacOS version 3.3.2, connected to home wifi. Here is the condition that I am facing:

1. OpenVPN client working after fresh install (load file ovpn and connect), It is connected and my IP address changed. But when I disconnected the vpn and connect again, I had connected but my IP was not changed, I can't access the web page, and I got this error log:

```
...
POST unix://[/var/run/agent_ovpnconnect.sock]/tun-setup : 200 OK
{
    "iface_name" : "utun2",
    "layer" : "OSI_LAYER_3",
    "tun_prefix" : true
}
/sbin/ifconfig utun2 down
/sbin/ifconfig utun2 192.168.1.11 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.252.0 mtu 1500 up
/sbin/route add -net 192.168.0.0 -netmask 255.255.252.0 192.168.1.11
add net 192.168.0.0: gateway 192.168.1.11
/sbin/route add -net xx.xx.xx.198 -netmask 255.255.255.255 192.168.0.1
add net xx.xx.xx.198: gateway 192.168.0.1
/sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 -netmask 128.0.0.0 192.168.0.1
add net 0.0.0.0: gateway 192.168.0.1
/sbin/route add -net 128.0.0.0 -netmask 128.0.0.0 192.168.0.1
add net 128.0.0.0: gateway 192.168.0.1
MacDNSAction: FLAGS=F RD=1 SO=5000 DNS=8.8.8.8 DOM= ADS=
open utun2 SUCCEEDED
⏎[Dec 2, 2021, 23:11:08] Connected via utun2
⏎[Dec 2, 2021, 23:11:08] LZO-ASYM init swap=0 asym=1
⏎[Dec 2, 2021, 23:11:08] Comp-stub init swap=0
⏎[Dec 2, 2021, 23:11:08] MTU mssfix=1410 crypto_encap=58 transport_encap=0
⏎[Dec 2, 2021, 23:11:08] EVENT: CONNECTED xx.xx.xx.198:14922 (xx.xx.xx.198) via /UDPv4 on utun2/192.168.1.11/ gw=[192.168.0.1/]
⏎[Dec 2, 2021, 23:11:08] UDP send exception: send: No route to host
⏎[Dec 2, 2021, 23:11:08] UDP send exception: send: No route to host
...
```

- Note: focus on `UDP send exception: send: No route to host`

2. With the same network (home wifi) and same ovpn config, I have no issue while connecting VPN with OpenVPN client from my Android phone.
3. With the same Macbook, same client vpn client, same ovpn config but connected from other networks(mobile hotspot), there is no issue.

Here is the config

```
setenv UV_ID 83c9fd53b2899844423bf7974eb7f1bc
setenv UV_NAME livel-3331
client
dev tun
dev-type tun
remote xx.xx.xx.198 14922 udp
nobind
persist-tun
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA1
verb 2
mute 3
push-peer-info
ping 10
ping-restart 60
hand-window 70
server-poll-timeout 4
reneg-sec 2592000
sndbuf 393216
rcvbuf 393216
max-routes 1000
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo no
key-direction 1
mssfix 1410
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, you have a route conflict - your home wifi subnet overlaps with the VPN Server's private address range. if possible try readdressing your home wifi network and use for it something different from 192.168.0.1 or set it to 172.16.0.0/16 ranges or if you have configured that VPN server then you can change the private IP address range on the server itself which should not in conflict with your home IP range.

Comment: I have encountered this several times.  Fix was simple once we figured out the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and found the solution on the forum.

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.openvpn.client.plist
```